Optical element that selectively attenuates a wavelength band without completely blocking it
I am looking for an optical element that would allow me to selectively attenuate a given wavelength by a factor of let's say between 2 to 5 without attenuating any other wavelength.
I know that notch filters have similar properties but they completely block light in the associated band. Do similar filters that attenuate light without completely blocking it exist? Are they commercially available?
Thanks for your help.

yes,  they exist ... yes, they are commercially avaliable

No they don't exist at least not "without attenuating any other wavelength" and yet they are commercially available as someone would bet that someone is not going to take your "any" literally.

If the width and accuracy of the rejection band has tight requirements, filters or coating companies could produce it for a price, which decreases with quantity ordered (this is just one example of such company). If you are on a budget, you can look at colored glass filters and light balancing filters. Such filters have lower optical density (OD) compared to laser-grade notch filters, and they more often come in as band-pass, as opposed to notch (note that 2 to 5 times attenuation corresponds to OD 0.3-0.7 respectively). You could look at HOYA's selection of light balancing filters LB40, LB80, and LB120 for exapmle: https://hoyaoptics.com/colored-glass-filters/light-balancing-filters-la-lb/. Schott and other glass manufacturers have a selection of colored glass filters. EDIT: I have no affiliation with any of the companies mentioned. The website RP Photonitcs, with which I am also not affiliated, has a more exhaustive list of glass manufacturers that might be able to produce colored glass: rp-photonics.com/bg/buy_optical_glasses.html.

please describe your affiliation with the three companies you linked

No affiliation, first company was found from a Google search (keywords were something like: custom optical notch filter). HOYA and Schott are popular manufacturers (I forgot how I learnt about them sorry). There are many more of course (that I am not affiliated with): CDGM, Corning, ...etc. RP Phonotics has a more exhaustive list (https://www.rp-photonics.com/bg/buy_optical_glasses.html). I am not affiliated with RP Photonics either. Note that not all glass manufacturers make colored glasses.

please add the info to the question ... a comment is not appropriate for it
